# Raw sensor data in Android devices

Tags: android, android-sensors

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) it looks like the Android Platform can provide raw measurement data. But I have read somewhere else that actually at the chip level (e.g. InvenSense chips) some data fusion algorithms are being carried out.

So how to know whether these outputs from the Android API's have already passed a data fusion algorithm or not? By data fusion we refer to the regular Kalman Filter or Complimentary Filter, or any other similar algorithm, which might possibly be proprietary.